# Default Constraint value Entity Framework Core 6 at insert into SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having a issue when I try to do an insert into a table which has a default constraint that generates a unique GUID.

This is my table:

[image: Table]

And this is the default constraint:

```
DEFAULT (abs(checksum(newid())%(90000000))) FOR [rap_number].
```

When I tried to save a new record, the GUID column `[rap_number]` remains in zero.

```
 RaffelPromo raffelPromo = RaffelPromoDTO.FromDTOToDB(raffelPromoDTOList[i]);
 await dbContext.RaffelPromos.AddAsync(raffelPromo);
 await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is the class `RaffelPromo` generated by Entity Framework Core:

```
public partial class RaffelPromo
{
    public string rap_mandt { get; set; } = null!;
    public int rap_id { get; set; }
    public int rap_sup_id { get; set; }
    public int rap_user_id { get; set; }
    public int rap_number { get; set; }
    public DateTime rap_date_ini { get; set; }
    public DateTime rap_date_end { get; set; }
    public bool rap_sts { get; set; }
    public DateTime rap_date_create { get; set; }

    public virtual SubclassPromo rap_ { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual UserPromo rap_Navigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Using SQL statement and not sending the rap_number into the insert a GUID is generated, but in EF Core, I need to pass a value. I am using a database-first approach.

Comment: `rap_number` must be configured as [database-generated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations&source=docs#explicitly-configuring-value-generation).

Comment: Thank you i saw that added this line an it works entity.Property(e => e.rap_number).HasDefaultValue(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Note that `rap_number` is *not* a GUID; it merely uses `NEWID()`, which generates a GUID, to produce a pseudo-random number between 0 and 90M. Even if `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` perfectly distributed its values (and I'm pretty sure it doesn't), the infamous birthday paradox makes collisions more probable than you might think. This may or may not be an issue for your use case, and is not directly related to using EF, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the new observations, i keep it in mind.